# url not loading in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

i have a tab bar control. 1st tab contains a navigation control. On the 2nd tab i want to load a web page (say google.com). I have written the code as

**NPIViewController.h**

```
@interface NPIViewController : UIViewController {
   IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

**NPIViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
  [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];         
  [self.webView loadRequest:request];               
}
```

The page just does not load. No compilation or runtime errors. What is wrong in this ?

Comment: does it show something ? is it working?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

to know whats wrong you can do this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  webView.delegate = self;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
  [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];         
  [self.webView loadRequest:request];               
}
```

add this new method in your class

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
```

I hope you have connected webView object with its outlet in Interface builder?

Thanks,

Comment: Ravin, i added this method. but there is nothing on the console. No page load. I have also made a connection to webView from the IB.

Comment: is webView is declared as property? if not then instead of using [self.webView loadRequest:request]; use [webView loadRequest:request]; this.(remove self. from self.webView) thanks

Comment: In the .h file i have made the webView as a property. Can you verify the code i have mentioned? Is it correct? I just took it from example codes on net.

Comment: have you set delegate as I have written in above code webView.delegate = self? try without self.webView, use webView.

Comment: what about delegate setting? NSLog(@"URL : %@",url);

Comment: I got this working. Actually the mistake was on my part. In the IB, i had wrongly connected the webView with the UIView object. The correct thing is to connect the UIview with the view & the webView with the UIWebView object.

Thanks @Ravin for pointing out.

Comment: FOR FUTURE GOOGLERS: To remove compiler warning, you may want to implement <UIWebViewDelegate> in your AppDelegate interface.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use https instead of http. If you use http you will get this error message (use Ravin's code to see the error):

"The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

Answer (score 2):

Create you webView

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Try this code

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Restart** your **IOS simulator**.
It is really not evident, but at first check some site in Safari at IOS simulator.
After restart of IOS simulator, my *webView* opened successfully both at simulator and device.

See this [famous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost) link.