# Why NSURLConnection failed with Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.”

Tags: objective-c

I am getting error -

**Error:** `Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost.`

```
UserInfo=0x10e74380 {NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.
```

I am facing the this error on devices. First request works very well. But when I put the data from the response of first request into second one, it always gives `error -1005`. This is happens in iOS 8 only. More than 100 users for our app reported this issue. Its happening on device and simulator both. We are using **https** , **POST** request. If I put the second request in place if first then it works. Which means problem occurs when I make the second request. Can we do anything from app side to fix this issue?

Comment: What don't you understand about that message?

Comment: Checkout the answers on another thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost?lq=1

Comment: Hey have you solved this bugs. I am  facing this same problem

Comment: @Bhumica Actually the data coming from server was too big to be handled by iPad. So we cut it down into to. And it started working fine. I am sure there would be some simple solution out there. But I couldn't find anything other than this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the implementation of the underlying [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/)class which is found only in IOS 8 you have to either turn off keep alive flag in the server eg. for Apache: `BrowserMatch "^iOS/8\." nokeepalive`

or handle the error in your code and retry the request upon which it works.