# Disable keepalive on Nginx for iOS/OSX NSURLConnection

Tags: nginx, keep-alive

Due to an IOS 8 bug, I want to disable keepalive temporary on my nginx server.

I tried this:

```
keepalive_disable safari;
keepalive_timeout 0;
```

I'm not sure for the browser name for iOS SDK...

Actually, I can always see that in my HTTP header on my app:

> Connection = "keep-alive";

How to disable keep-alive for iOS NSURLConnection or, if not possible, how to disable it for all requests.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

This answer is for Apache, but I think it will give you a clue for nginx - [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)