# Getting "null" reverseGeocodeCoordinate method with GMSMap in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, location, geocode

I am using the following code to get address from lat and long:

```
NSLog(@">>>>%f,%f",location.latitude,location.longitude);

[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:location completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *resp, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"response%@",resp);
 }];
```

When I try to do geocode with a correct lat and long, for a particular location, I get null as response and error is this. This is not happening with my android device.

I can see response as nil and error is:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x1659ae80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972822/error-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1001-the-request-timed-out

Comment: try to update Google Maps SDK into latest, check internet is connected or not.

Comment: Its not an internet issue, am getting correct result for all expect that particular location in ios

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises because of your API key is expired, if you regenerate the API key in google console it will work and get your response

API key example: `AIzaSyDleduRwellp3OwLMAOzLt4MZWsJMWqMvM`

Answer (score 0):

Also check, if you're using simulator, that your simulator location setting is set to `none`. You can check via selecting your simulator and go to:

> Debug > Location > none

Hope it helps.