# I want to consume login API (nodejs) using alamofire on swift

Tags: node.js, swift, alamofire

there is my code

```
@IBAction func btn_login(_ sender: Any) {


//        let serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.34:1337/login"
        let serverUrl = "http://10.0.0.10:1337/login"

        guard let email = emailtf.text, !email.isEmpty else {return}
        guard let password = passwordtf.text, !password.isEmpty else {return}


      let loginRequest = [
                   "email" : email,
                   "password" : password
               ]
        Alamofire.request(serverUrl, method: .post, parameters: loginRequest, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
            print(responseObject)
            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                print(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

and im getting this error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

```
<4548B0C2-A5AD-4F23-8A9D-6A02F84FE3A9>.<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000009e6b20 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <4548B0C2-A5AD-4F23-8A9D-6A02F84FE3A9>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <4548B0C2-A5AD-4F23-8A9D-6A02F84FE3A9>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10 (maybe even earlier?), you can only make HTTPS requests -- HTTP requests will trigger an error, just like in your code.

So change your server url to:

```
    let serverUrl = "https://10.0.0.10:1337/login"
```

Comment: same error, i tried everything maybe but still doesn't work

Comment: Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972822/error-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1001-the-request-timed-out Could be coming from your simulator. Maybe try restarting it, or running your code on a physical device.