# AFNetworking Network Connection Lost

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator, afnetworking-2

I read this protected answer:

[Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

I get the error in the latest Xcode release 6.1 (6A1052d) simulator for 8.1.
Im using AFNetworking 2.4.1

What I tried:

1. Resetting contents on the simulator
2. Deleting derived data
3. Switching to 7.1 as someone suggested
4. Posting to Parse Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/XbL4AkKbEv4

Im thinking my case may be different because everyone seems to get it to work by restarting the simulator but I can't.

Comment: Did you read the second answer to that question?

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't it.  I had to move over to NSURLSessionDataTask instead of AFHTTPOperations.