# TWTRLogInButton - NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, nsurl, twitter-fabric

I am getting the following error:

> error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error
>   -1012.)

This error appears in the console when I press the 'Log in with Twitter' button, which is created like so (exactly as it appears in the app):

```
    TWTRLogInButton* logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession* session, NSError* error) {
        if (session) {

            NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);


        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

I don't see the NSLog for the error or 'signed in as %@'.

The error occurs when running the app on the iPhone 6S running iOS 9.1.

Fabric is up to date, version 1.12.0.  However I have the following warnings:

> Umbrella header for module 'TwitterKit' does not include header
>   'TWTRDefines.h'
>
> Umbrella header for module 'TwitterKit' does not include header
>   'TWTRSession.h'

I am unsure if they are causing the problem - but skeptical as it runs on simulator and other devices.

In developer settings on the phone I have set 'Allow HTTP Services' to ON and in my.plist file I have set the key Allow Arbitrary Keys to YES as this appeared to solve the problem before.

Any advice would be appreciated as I am truly lost.

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost/25996971#25996971

Comment: This looks weird. Have you removed the app and cleaned your build folder ?

Comment: No luck cleaning the build folder.  @SeanChense that didn't work either but thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Using a new iPhone cable? Also see: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an ongoing discussion of the -1012 error on the Twitter developer forum here:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-twitter-kit-1-10-1-twtrloginbutton-responds-with-1012-error/52766

I downloaded this sample project posted by user `michalhernas`, which claims to replicate the issue: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1824765/test-twitter.zip1

With the latest version of TwitterKit (1.13.1), the error message has changed to:

> Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=32 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401), NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Could not authenticate you. (code 32)}

So, it's at least a different error. I would keep an eye on the Twitter thread. Funny enough I tried to post this there, but got an error when trying to authorize the forum app.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve the problem by completely removing TwitterKit libraries from XCode, delete the project from fabric.io and make a fresh installation of TwitterKit.

This is an issue in the TwitterKit and is already being investigated https://twittercommunity.com/t/xcode-7-twitterkit-warning/52390

**Edit**: And of course - what I always suggest - remove the `derivedData`, clean , clean build folder, restart XCode and remove & reinstall your app.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with Application Transport Security.

You can whitelist domains to exempt them from this security or disable completely.  The following link outlines the ways to approach this problem and solve it.

http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/

I hope this helps.