# SoundCloud API: GET request fails with code -1005, using iOS/Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, soundcloud, alamofire

I'm working on an iOS app where SoundCloud users log in with OAuth in a web view and then the app makes HTTP requests to the SoundCloud API via Alamofire. I've successfully authenticated the user and stored their token (using [ABMSoundCloudAPI](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)), but GET requests to https://api.soundcloud.com/me are failing with a -1005 error, "The network connection was lost." This seems to be a common problem with iOS as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost), however resetting the simulator doesn't solve the problem for me and the problem also occurs when using a device. I've also tried:

- Removing and re-adding the wifi network
- Retrying the request programmatically if it fails
- Adding a header with "Connection": "Close"

I see the same error in every case. Are there other headers I should try? I'm using these libraries via Cocoapods:

- ABMSoundCloudAPI (0.2.1)
- AFNetworking (2.6.1)
- AFOAuth2Manager (2.2.0)
- Alamofire (3.1.2)
- SwiftyJSON (2.3.1)

Here is my code:

```
var retryCount = 0

func getUserInfo(token:String) {
    let headers = ["Connection": "Close"]
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=\(token)", parameters: ["client_id":clientId], encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print("error calling GET on /me")
                print(response.result.error)
                if self.retryCount < 2 {
                    if let token = self.defaults.stringForKey("sc_key_token") {
                        self.getUserInfo(token)
                        ++self.retryCount
                    }
                }
                return
            }

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }


            let user = JSON(value)

            print("User info: " + user.description)

    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x126248c10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=USER_TOKEN, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=USER_TOKEN, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was caused by the request encoding. When I switched from .JSON to .URL, the 1005 error went away.