# Alamofire Request error: NSURLErrorDomain Code -1005 The network connection was lost

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rest, alamofire

I'm working on transferring my project from AFNetworking to Alamofire. Really like the project. However, I'm receiving this error when attempting to make a GET request.

Here's some example code:

```
class func listCloudCredntials(onlyNew onlyNew: Bool = true, includePending: Bool = true) -> Request {

    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = includePending ? ["include_pending": "true"] : [:]

    let urlString = "https://myapp-staging.herokuapp.com/api/1/credntials"

    let token = SSKeychain.storedToken()

    let headers: [String: String] = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]

    return Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
}
```

Then, in my VC:

```
listCloudCredntials().validate().responseJSON() {
    (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in

    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let result):
        printCR("success: \(result)")

    case .Failure(let error):
        printCR("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Here's the error I'm running into:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was
>   lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14e9c77f0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myapp-staging.herokuapp.com/api/1/credntials,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myapp-staging.herokuapp.com/api/1/credntials,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

I've tried running on the iOS Simulator with 1OS 8.4 and iOS 9.1, as well as my iPhone 6S running iOS 9.1.

What am I doing wrong?

--------**EDIT**--------

**To clarify, this function works just fine with AFNetworking.**

Here's the debugprint(request) result (it's a GET request):

```
$ curl -i \
-H "Authorization: Bearer some-JWT-Security-Token" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5" \
-H "User-Agent: Company/com.Company.AppName (1081; OS Version 9.2 (Build 13C75))" \
-d "{\"include_pending\":\"true\"}" \
"https://appname-staging.herokuapp.com/api/1/credntials"
```

I have to change curl -i to curl -X GET in order for the curl to return successfully.

Here is another call that I'm required to make in the app that works with no issues.

```
curl -i \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5" \
-H "User-Agent: Company/com.Company.AppName (1081; OS Version 9.2 (Build 13C75))" \
-d "{\"token\":\"UserSessionTokenString\"}" \
"https://appname-staging.herokuapp.com/api/1/authenticate/user"
```

Could it be something with the GET vs. POST?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resolved! I was using JSON encoding for a GET request. Here's the answer: [Alamofire Request error only on GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421809/alamofire-request-error-only-on-get-requests/34421967#34421967)

Answer (score -2):

If you retain the request in your vc or other object, this error would be gone.

Comment: Incorrect, I just tried it and it failed. See updated code above.