# afnetworking try to connect after unsuccessful connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetwrorking. After sending request sometimes i get

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "Network connection is lost."
```

Even when internet is available sometimes it randomly occurs. The second or the third try the request works.

Is there any way to restart this request if the first one fails. I mean is there a parameter in operationManager to set the number of tries?

here is how im using AFNetworking:

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    operationManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [operationManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[operationManager POST:URL
                parameters:parameters
                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  ......
```

Comment: this is well known networking issue ...you can check here ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost

Comment: @EICaptain seems like that issue was on ios8 emulator, but i have it on the real device

Comment: no its not a simulator issue...Ya sometimes it works on reset content settings but its not solved problem fully ...check this link and check a post of matt .......https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314

Comment: Unfortunately, because this appears to be a bug in the underlying Foundation URL Loading System, there is no real way for AFNetworking to work around this issue.

Comment: @EICaptain ok. thanks man. I will try to call the request twice