# How can I add the http header "Connection :close" correctly in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, http

I have a swift app. It sends http requests to a server that I cannot access myself.

When the app is at the background for a while, and I return and try to send a request to the server I get an http error "the connection is lost".

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25996971/311130)

And I want to add connection:close header and value, as suggested.

I have tried this code:

```
func taskForGETMethod(method: String, pathParameters: [String], parameters: [String : AnyObject], completionHandler: (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask {

    /* 1. Build the URL and configure the request */
    let urlString = Constants.BaseURLSecure + method + HttpClient.escapedPath(pathParameters) + HttpClient.escapedParameters(parameters)
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue("Connection", forKey: "close")
```

but all my request's are failing now. How can I add the header correctly?

Comment: Hi. How do you solve this issue?

Comment: @Sarit, I know this is old thread, but check my answer in case you are wondering what was the issue.

Comment: @o15a3d4l11s2 Sorry. I leave mobile world for long time already

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the http header values you need to use `NSMutableURLRequest` and the following API

```
func setValue(_ value: String?, forHTTPHeaderField field: String)
```

like so

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://yo", relativeToURL: nil)
let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
req.setValue("close", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
```

**Swift 3**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://yo", relativeTo: nil)
let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! )
req.setValue("close", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
```

Comment: There is an outdated (2005) topic in Apple Mailing Lists, about ignoring "Connection" header in this case - https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2005/Oct/msg00037.html. Not sure if it still valid or not.

Comment: That's really intriguing. I wonder if `NSURLRequest` does the same thing. I should have a look at the actual outbound request some time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line

```
request.setValue("Connection", forKey: "close")
```

The key is the title of the header, which should be "Connection" and its value should be "close". To put it simple, at the moment you are setting ***close = Connection*** and not ***Connection = close***.

You need to change the line to

```
request.setValue("close", forKey: "Connection")
```

Comment: Worked for me using Swift 5 and iOS 13.3.