# AFNetworking : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost.", _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, post, afnetworking

I need to call a web service (post) on every 30 seconds. For first 3-4 times it works fine , but after 3-4 hits it gives error :

**Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=My_URL, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4.**

Please note that, Same web service hits from android app and postman then it works fine for everytime (no matter how many times you hit).   I am using iphone device, I have also tried on simulator but still same issue. I have also checked my enitre code (check all values at run time before call web services) , all is fine. Any idea what's going wrong. **Any suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: this might due your internet connection

Comment: Unfortunately, because this appears to be a bug in the underlying Foundation URL Loading System, there is no real way for AFNetworking to work around this issue. . check this link and post of matt ... https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314

Comment: possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost

Comment: @ Milap Kundalia , internet is stable and  working 100 % I have confirmed. Furthermore ,This is not dublicate question, Because I have alreday tried many solutions like : **Restarting the simulator** (you have shared this link). which may resolve my this issue. But still facing same problem. That's why I have asked this question from my side.

Comment: @Monusingh did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue :(

Comment: @ Robert TuanVu , I have used latest AFNetworking and improved my code , and worked for me. Let you try also please. thanks.