# Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, afnetworking

I am facing the below error:

> {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "The network
>   connection was lost."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xxxxxx,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxxxx, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

I already referred some answers for same question, but I am failed to solve this issue.

1. I checked internet connection.
2. I checked resetting the simulator and some other ways

I am using `AFNetworking` and the following code snippet to make the network call:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:url parameters:finalDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      NSLog(@"JSON: %@",responseObject);
       *********
       *********
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
  }
}];
```

I am using currently Xcode 7.2 and simulator 9.2. few answers in this site for the same issue I really not understood. Can anyone help me what is the issue about?

Comment: restart your  simulator and check , for more deatails check this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2546

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : already i did that but no use

Comment: ok check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : already i checked that..but i not understood few answers..atleast say 1 thing ,is this issue related to app side or may be from server side, b'coz this is working from 1 month.but suddenly from yesterday i am facing this issue

Comment: are you added the `LSApplicationQuerySchemes` in your plist

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : not added...but upto my knowledge we will add LSApplicationQuerySchemes when we are using facebook SDK

Comment: not like that bro , in ios 9 and above for connection purpose LSApplicationQuerySchemes needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)