# Weird and Unsolvable Alamofire Issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

Please read the question properly before downvoting.

There is no similar questions like this in SO.

I have in fact browser SO for a few hourse before deciding to ask.

There is a noticably weird bug I have found in Alamofire.

This problem only occur when the screen is locked when the app is on the foreground

Steps to Reproduce

1. While App in the Foreground
2. Lock Phone
3. Unlock Phone
4. Trigger a request with Alamofire. <- This first request will always fail `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was > lost.`
5. **Every single request after this will get a proper response (success).** Unless if the phone is locked again while it is in the foreground.

Can anyone using Alamofire find a fix to this?

N.B.: This problem found on Alamofire 4.0 and below. I have personally tested this on Alamofire 2.0 and it also has the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

Comment: @NazmulHasan NO this is not a duplicate. Please read the question properly

Comment: Please dont vote down a question you have not even read properly @NazmulHasan . Duplicate? Oh please.

Comment: where you tested ? device or simulator ?

Comment: This could be related to the Keep-alive answer on the question @NazmulHasan referred to. You might want to give it a shot

Comment: @lostInTransit First of all, even if that is the case, that is not a proper way of mark as duplicate. And lastly, no, that answer does not work.

Comment: @JayVDiyk do you solved your problem ?