# UNIRest Https "The network connection was lost" Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, https, unirest

I'm developing an IOS app, and I'm using my own created web services hosting in a windows server. I'm also using SSL certificate from RapidSSL.

I'm using UniRest Objective-C library, [Unirest Lib >>](http://unirest.io/objective-c.html) and When I try to request https address, I'm getting this error.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was
>   lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1702501a0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "The network connection was
>   lost."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myapi.com/authorize.aspx,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myapi.com/authorize.aspx,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myapi.com/authorize.aspx,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myapi.com/authorize.aspx,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

But If I request same adress with http protocol, There is no error!

Info.plist here;

[image]

I've just realized, Safari also can't open page! Weird!

I can open page on desktop Chrome and desktop Firefox but desktop Safari can't open too.

Here is my Code:

```
 +(void)RunAuthApiWithUsername:(NSString *)username Password:(NSString *)password completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSString* title, NSString* message))completionBlock
{
    NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"
                              };
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": username,
                             @"password": password
                             };

    [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:API_AUTHORIZE_URL];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = response.body.JSONObject;
        NSString* isSuccess = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"success"];
        if([isSuccess isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            completionBlock(YES, nil, nil);
        }
        else{
            completionBlock(NO, [jsonDict objectForKey:@"title"], [jsonDict objectForKey:@"message"]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25996971/944634

Comment: I am not using Unirest Library anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue, and it looks like it is not a timeout issue. I'm experiencing it while using Alamofire, and I think this is somehow related to TLS issues, as this is something we changed on the server side.