# How to disable Apache keep-alive only for iOS?

Tags: apache, cpanel, keep-alive, whm

Is it possible to disable keep-alive mechanism in apache for only iOS clients through CPanel?
I have found this question as a solution:
[Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

But I cannot find the file setenvif.conf.
How should I edit the setenvif.conf?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Would a appreciate a short feedback :)

Comment: Thank you mate. :) And sorry for my lateness. Yes it work for me.

Comment: no problem and you are welcome :) was just wondering if it worked, since I didn't test it, just assumed it from other applications of this 'nokeepalive'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need this exact conf-file. Just put it in your default server config:

```
BrowserMatch "iOS \d\." nokeepalive
```