# Codename One Networking issue on ios

Tags: ios, networking, codenameone

After a recent update we've been getting some major issues with networking on iOS in our Codename One app.

Everything works for a short time and then network requests start failing with the error;

"The network connection was lost."

It seems like it may be realated to the issue described here;
[Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

I attempted to add the "Connection : close" header to the apps network requests but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: One big change related to networking we had in this update is a change to cookie parsing code, could this be related?

Comment: I'm not too sure. I did notice this warning when I built from source;  "Warning: Cookie tried to set to another domain".  
There was also a ParseException on the network thread; "Invalid year value2017-11-06"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be resolved in the latest update, there was indeed an issue with cookie handling in some cases.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. However I now seem to be unable to upload the build to Apple. Application loader is complaining about a .a binary file in the bundle. In this case it's libzbar.a which is used in the barcode scanning library. This is something that's been in the app for a long time. If you like I can make a seperate post for this apparently unrelated issue

Comment: Please ask a separate question with a screenshot from the application loader