# Get Response using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Alamofire to make Get Response but unable to get the Valid Response . I am using below details . I dono where i am making mistake.
    let myID = MEGHA-WORK SE-107

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)" , "ID": (myID).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ]
 let parameters:Parameters = ["ID": (myID).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)]

 let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
       manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60

        manager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString , headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
              debugPrint(response)
                if  response.response?.statusCode == 200 || response.response?.statusCode == 201 {
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print(json)
                        completion(json, nil)
                    }
                }

Task <343CF648-7C9A-4E03-9A82-A88BC41EA926>.<6> finished with error - code: -1005

Response 

[Request]: GET https://my-services.myservices.com:443/prweb/api/v1/cases?ID=MEGHA-WORK%20SE-107
[Response]: nil
[Data]: 0 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x109ce9500 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x10d53db00 [0x1b271c310]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bba06d196d0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://my-services.myservices.com:443/prweb/api/v1/cases?ID=MEGHA-WORK%20SE-107, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://my-services.myservices.com:443/prweb/api/v1/cases?ID=MEGHA-WORK%20SE-107, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 553592494.567, "Initial Response Time": 553592497.615, "Request Completed Time": 553592497.615, "Serialization Completed Time": 553592497.616, "Latency": 3.049 secs, "Request Duration": 3.049 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 3.049 secs }
```

Comment: Did you try your URL in browser ? I think it is not working.

Comment: Instead of `URLEncoding.queryString` use `JSONEncoding.default`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason is already printed there:

> Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

Restarting the simulator and erasing all content and settings seems to fix this for others (Simulator->Hardware->Erase All Content and Settings...)

[Please check this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this way :

```
if (responseJson.response?.statusCode)! > 200 && (responseJson.response?.statusCode)! < 300{
            // handle as appropriate because the response will be success

} else {

}
```

It may helps you to handle the crash. Thank you